# select boot device on American Megatrends BIOS Version B3W6_NA123C.029 05/05/2017 13:55:49

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, multi-boot

I am trying to boot a Laptop with the American Megatrends BIOS from a different boot device.

The setup shows Boot option priorities "Windows Boot Manager" and "UEFI: Built-in EFI...".

There is also an "OS Slelect" (!) with the options "Windows" and "Linux".

But I did not find any option to boot from USB/CD/Lan.

What do I need to do?

Comment: You need to connect the USB device and then select it. And this is because you don't have BIOS but UEFI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try the following ways to troubleshoot the issue:

1. We need to set the setting of "Boot From a USB Drive or CD".
   Restart your computer and wait for that first screen to pop up. Often, it’ll say something like “Press F12 to Choose Boot Device” somewhere on the screen. Press that key.

[image]

For details we can refer the article: [How to Boot From a USB Drive or CD on Any Computer](https://lifehacker.com/5991848/how-to-boot-from-a-cd-or-usb-drive-on-any-pc)

2. We need to plug in the USB device or CD, if we have already plugged in the USB device or CD, it may also be that the computer does not recognize the USB or CD device, try replacing the USB device with the USB interface.
3. Turn off **Secure Boot**, then view if we can see the option to boot from USB/CD/Lan.

[image]

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia before I posted the original question, I had tried to boot from a USB-CDROM, which did not work. I also tried the above, but did not get a boot device selection. After posting the question, i copied the CD to an USB stick and it worked. So I still do not know how to select boot precedence, but managed to install an altenative OS, therefore I no longer need to solve the original problem and consider the case closed. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with this BIOS is that there is no dedicated boot from other device/interface menu. You can however, force a boot from another device in the BIOS, which is basically what we're after. To achieve this do the following

Press the Delete Key on startup
move across to the Save & Exit Tab
Towards the bottom of the page is a "boot override" section
select the desired boot location from here.